# Download file using HttpClient while also sending POST data

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to send a json POST request and save the file returned. This is my code:

```
  var obj = new {data = "zip", name = "h.zip"};
  string objString =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
  StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(objString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, downloadUrl))
    {

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(downloadUrl, stringContent);
        Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);

        var contentStream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(contentStream); // debugger confirms that there is a file present
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\mainuser\Desktop\downloadtest\file.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, Int32.MaxValue)){
          Console.WriteLine("copying started");
          await contentStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
          Console.WriteLine("never gets printed");
        }
    }
  }
```

It successfully creates a file.zip, but it maintains to be 0KB in size. Also,  `Console.WriteLine("never gets printed");` never executes. What is the correct way of downloading file using `HttpClient`?

Comment: A buffer size of `int.MaxValue` is probably a very bad idea: this means that basically the entire file will be buffered in memory, before being written out in one go when the `FileStream` is disposed. The default is `4096`. You can just use `File.Create("...")` instead though. This explains why your file remains at 0KB in size, but not why it doesn't finish downloading.

Comment: Are you sure your file has finished downloading? Try looking at the request/response in Fiddler